# Why is the formal definition of Latin square equivalent with the informal?

Tags: universal-algebra, latin-square, quasigroups

Informally, a latin square is a table where each element appears exactly once in each row and each column.

I know that this is probrably not an official definition of, however, it should somehow match the formal definition, right?

My question is: how does the table matches the definition about $a * x = b$ and $y * a = b$ having unique solutions for all $a, b$? In the table, each element is also *unique* in any row or column, but I am still not able to connect it.

Thank you for help.

The definition I work with is from Bergman´s Universal Algebra: Fundamentals and Selected Topics:

[image]

Comment: If an element $b$ were to appear more than once in the column for an element say $a$, then there would be two elements $y_1, y_2$ with $y_1 \cdot a = b = y_2 \cdot a$. Hence the equation $y \cdot a = b$ does not have unique solutions.

Comment: @Rushy I get that, but I am maybe missing the connection between how the table is shaped and how that corresponds to the binary operation. Shouldn´t the "$y_1 * a = b$ say that $y_1$ is in particular row or column? If yes, what is the role of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @TerezaTizkova $y_1*a=b$ means that the element in line $y_1$ and column $a$ is $b$.

Comment: Definitions need not always be formal , if they have the necessary rigorousness. I do not know whether there is an "official" definition of a Latin square and how it looks like, but this is , in my opinion , an utterly valid definition. An equivlant definition would be, that every row and every column is a permutation of {$1,\cdots,n$}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In combinatorics, a *Latin square* can be defined as an $n \times n$ square matrix where each element (from a set of size $n$) appears exactly once in each row and each column.  The algebraic structure $\langle Q, \cdot \rangle$ is typically called a [*quasigroup*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup).

If $Q$ is finite, we can write out the multiplication table for $Q$, and maybe it'd look something like this
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc|}
\cdot & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
If we ignore the margins, we have matrix $L=L(i,j)$:
$$
\begin{array}{|cc|}
\hline
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}.
$$
Importantly, **the entry in cell $L(i,j) = i \cdot j$, by definition of $L$** (where $\cdot$ is the operation in $\langle Q, \cdot \rangle$).  Or, in other words $L(i,j)=k$ if and only if $i \cdot j = k$.

We can go from a Latin square $L$ to a quasigroup too (provided the symbol set $Q$ of $L$ is the same as its row and column indices), by defining $\cdot$ such that $i \cdot j = L(i,j)$ for all $i,j \in Q$.

Two distinct solutions to $a \cdot x = b$ in $\langle Q, \cdot \rangle$ would imply two distinct solutions to $L(a,x)=b$, thereby implying $b$ occurs twice in row $a$ in $L$, violating the Latin square property.  Conversely, if $b$ occurs twice in row $a$ in $L$, then there are two distinct solutions to $L(a,x)=b$, and thus two distinct solutions to $a \cdot x = b$ in $\langle Q, \cdot \rangle$, violating the quasigroup property.  (Likewise for columns and $x \cdot a = b$.)

Two caveats: (a) $\langle Q, \cdot \rangle$ might not be finite, in which case the combinatorial definition "appears exactly once in each row and each column" will need extending (what is a "row" when $Q$ is uncountable?).  (b) For the equivalence to work, we need the rows and columns of the Latin square to match the symbol set.